# Hover Image option on span that goes outside of div

Tags: html, css

I am creating a list of queries that when hovered would display an image.

I have tried changing z-indexes on multiple divs, changing positions from relative to absolute and the other way around.

```css
.naglowek2 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.naglowekbox2 {
  background-color: #c34f3f;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  border-top: 2px dashed #751b1b;
  border-left: 2px dashed #751b1b;
  border-right: 2px dashed #751b1b;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 3px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 3px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 3px #000000;
  text-shadow: 1px 0 0 #000000, -1px 0 0 #000000, 0 1px 0 #000000, 0 -1px 0 #000000, 1px 1px #000000, -1px -1px 0 #000000, 1px -1px 0 #000000, -1px 1px 0 #000000;
}

.naglowekboxinner2 {
  background-color: #303030;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 450px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #ffffff;
}


/* 08  */

.category-textzd1 {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.desc-togglezd1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#togglezd1-1 {
  display: none;
}

.category-descriptionzd1 {
  height: 0px;
  /* we start animation from 0px */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* without this the contents will be 
                                            * visible regardless of height */
  transition: height 0.5s ease-in;
  /* transition has to be defined on base state of element */
  background-color: #303030;
  /* make transition easier to observe */
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~.category-descriptionzd1 {
  height: 150px;
  /* change height when input is checked */
}


/* 08 Koniec */

.hover_imgzdself {
  display: inline-block;
}

.hover_imgzdself a {
  position: relative;
  cursor: help;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.hover_imgzdself a span {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: #c1c1c1;
}

.hover_imgzdself a:hover span {
  display: block;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div class='naglowekbox2'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-lg-12'>
        <p class='naglowek2'>H1/H2:</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-lg-6 naglowekboxinner2'>
        <center>
          <label class="desc-togglezd1" for="togglezd1-1">List</label>
        </center>
        <input type="checkbox" id="togglezd1-1">
        <div class="category-descriptionzd1">
          <p class="category-textzd1">
            <div class='hover_imgzdself'>
              <a>Picture One
                          <span>
                            <img src='03_menu/08_nowa_postac/02_zdolnosci/.png' />
                          </span>
                        </a>
            </div>
            &nbsp;&semi;
            <div class='hover_imgzdself'>
              <a>Picture Two
                          <span>
                            <img src='03_menu/08_nowa_postac/02_zdolnosci/.png' />
                          </span>
                        </a>
            </div>
            &nbsp;&semi;
            <div class='hover_imgzdself'>
              <a>Picture One
                          <span>
                            <img src='03_menu/08_nowa_postac/02_zdolnosci/.png' />
                          </span>
                        </a>
            </div>
            &nbsp;&semi;
            <div class='hover_imgzdself'>
              <a>Picture Two
                          <span>
                            <img src='03_menu/08_nowa_postac/02_zdolnosci/.png' />
                          </span>
                        </a>
            </div>
            &nbsp;&semi;
            <div class='hover_imgzdself'>
              <a>Picture One
                          <span>
                            <img src='03_menu/08_nowa_postac/02_zdolnosci/.png' />
                          </span>
                        </a>
            </div>
            &nbsp;&semi;
            <div class='hover_imgzdself'>
              <a>Picture Two
                          <span>
                            <img src='03_menu/08_nowa_postac/02_zdolnosci/.png' />
                          </span>
                        </a>
            </div>
            &nbsp;&semi;
            <div class='hover_imgzdself'>
              <a>Picture One
                          <span>
                            <img src='03_menu/08_nowa_postac/02_zdolnosci/.png' />
                          </span>
                        </a>
            </div>
            &nbsp;&semi;
            <div class='hover_imgzdself'>
              <a>Picture Two
                          <span>
                            <img src='03_menu/08_nowa_postac/02_zdolnosci/.png' />
                          </span>
                        </a>
            </div>
            &nbsp;&semi;
            <div class='hover_imgzdself'>
              <a>Picture One
                          <span>
                            <img src='03_menu/08_nowa_postac/02_zdolnosci/.png' />
                          </span>
                        </a>
            </div>
            &nbsp;&semi;
            <div class='hover_imgzdself'>
              <a>Picture Two
                          <span>
                            <img src='03_menu/08_nowa_postac/02_zdolnosci/.png' />
                          </span>
                        </a>
            </div>
            &nbsp;&semi;
          </p>
          <center>
            <label class="desc-togglepo1" style='font-size: 14px;' for="togglezd1-1">Zwiń</label>
          </center>
          <input type="checkbox" id="togglezd1-1">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style='height: 10px;'></div>
  </div>
</center>
```

When you click on "List" it opens up a list of options. The idea is that when you hover one of these options, it should show up a picture 200x100 px.
However if you go to the options on the far right, these pictures are not showing fully, as are cut to the size od the list box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the see the updated jsfiddle here.

https://jsfiddle.net/thanooshan/x3q1zjsf/5/

I removed `for="togglezd1-1"` from `<label class="desc-togglezd1 toggle-label">List</label>` in-order to prevent toggle effect. And added `toggle-label` class as a selector to get the toggle effect.

Then removed unnecessary styles and added `display: none` property.

```
.category-descriptionzd1 {
   display: none;
   background-color: #303030;
}
```

Now it removed the image crop issue. In-order to get the toggle effect back again. I achieved via following code.

```
$('.toggle-label').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

  $('.category-descriptionzd1').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working perfectly. I believe i need to learn a bit of JS in order to resolve my other problems:)

Comment: Quick questions, since I am not a JS user yet. Where the script should be included? I assume that out of <body>, but should it be in index head or somewhere else? As if I try this code on my side with JS at the bottom of the index file  between </body> and </html> it is not expanding my list

Comment: @Blade007zg First you need to include `jQuery` to the project. Add this line of code `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` in your `<head>` tag. Then place the above JS script bottom of the page before `</body>` tag. It should work fine. You can place JS script in the `<head>` tag but sometimes JS script triggers even before DOM elements creates, then if will give errors. So, it's better to place the code in bottom of the page.

Comment: Hi Thanooshan, I have included jquery in head section and the script in between <script></script> before </body>. Unfortunately this has not resolved the issue. List still does not expand.

Comment: Ok, found out what was the issue. Basically I had already 2 versions of jquery included in Head section. Had to add 
<script>
var jqVERSIONS = jQuery.noConflict();
</script> under each according to version in order to avoid conflicts

Comment: @Blade007zg I'm glad that you fixed your issue.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of the `overflow: hidden` in `.category-descriptionzd1`. If I remove that, it works for me.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that, however since removing hidden overflow, all the text shows up no matter if you click List or not. The only thing that works when clicking on List is that background expandes